# Selenium Web Driver

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to select Check In and Check out time in "http://www.kayak.co.in/?ispredir=true" through the web driver. Not able to select any date. Please can help me.

Comment: Did U try select unique selector in browser or selenium ide ??

Answer (score 1):

Do not mess with Datepicker. Insread use `sendKeys()`

For check in date you can use

```
driver.findElement(By.Id("travel_dates-start-placeholder")).sendKeys("01/01/2015");
```

Comment: And then veryfi by getText().

Answer (score 0):

```
WebElement checkin = driver.findelement(by.xpath(".//*[@id='travel_dates-start-wrapper']/span[1]"));
checkin.click();
WebElement checkout = driver.findelement(by.xpath(".//*[@id='travel_dates-end-wrapper']/span[1]"));
checkout.click();
```

Please let me if this works..